# Given graph $G=(V,E)$ and weight function $w\,:\,E\to\mathbb{N}$, function $f(G,w)$ finds the heaviest clique in the graph, prove $L(M)=CLIQUE$

Tags: graphs, np, clique

Given graph $G=(V,E)$ and weight function $w\,:\,E\to\mathbb{N}$, function $f(G,w)$ finds the heaviest clique in the graph, when the sum of a clique is the sum of the weights on all of the edges.

I want to prove that there is a Turing machine $M$ so I will get $L(M)=CLIQUE$, using function $f$, where $CLIQUE$ is the language of all $(G,k)$ so $G$ has a clique of size $k$.

I wrote the following algorithm:

> $M$ on $(G,k)$:
>
> 1. Build a weight function $w$ so each edge in $G$ gets $1$.
> 2. Calculate $f(G,w)$.
> 3. Accepts if and only if $f(G,w)\geq k$.

My professor noted that it should be $f(G,w)\geq {k \choose 2}$. Is it possible to explain why?

Answer (score 2):

A clique $C$ on $k$ vertices has $\binom{k}{2}$ edges, i.e., all unordered pairs $\{a,b\}$ such that $a$ and $b$ are distinct vertices in $C$.

The number of such pairs is $\frac{k (k-1)}{2} = \binom{k}{2}$. You can count these by focusing on the number of *ordered* pairs first.
To make an ordered pair $(a,b)$ you have $k$ choices for $a$ and $k-1$ choice for $b$ (i.e., all vertices in $C$ except for $a$). The number of ordered pairs is then $k(k-1)$. To get the number of *unordered* pairs you only need to divide the above quantity by $2$ since, for each unordered pair $\{a,b\}$, we counted both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$.